# Join rectangles by labeled arrows

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, labels, chain

I need to connect the rectangles by labeled arrows (rights) in this case:

```
     \documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
     \usetikzlibrary{arrows, chains}

     \begin{document}
         \begin{tikzpicture}[
       node distance = 0mm,
         start chain = going right,
          box/.style = {draw, semithick, minimum size=1cm, 
               outer sep = 3mm, on chain,}
                    ]
     \foreach \i  in {{\Huge S_0}, S_1, S_2, S_3, S_4, S_5, S_6, S_7, S_8}
        \node[box,label=below:] {$\i$};

     \end{tikzpicture}
     \end{document}
```

I need also label arrows with `\lambda_n` where n is number from 0 to 7. Labels should be placed above the arrows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without `chains`, only two simple `\foreach` loops:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[box/.style = {draw, semithick, minimum size=1cm}]
  \foreach \n in {0,...,8}
    \node at (1.7*\n, 0) [box] (\n) {$S_\n$};
  \foreach \n [count=\i] in {0,...,7}
    \draw[-{latex}] (\n) -- node[above] {$\lambda_\n$} (\i);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Add the arrows as further nodes `on chain`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, chains}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}%
   [node distance = 0mm,
    start chain = going right,
    box/.style = {draw, semithick, minimum size=1cm, on chain}
   ]
   \foreach \i  in {0,...,7}
     {\node[box,label=below:] {$S_\i$};
      \node[on chain] {$\stackrel{\lambda_\i}\longrightarrow$};
     }
   \node[box,label=below:] {$S_8$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a way to remove spaces between arrows and boxes?

Comment: @VasyaPravdin Sorry, I was not able to come back to you earlier. See Ignasi's answer for a solution without spaces between arrows and boxes.

Answer (score 3):

Without chains and only one loop

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}%
   [
    box/.style = {draw, semithick, minimum size=1cm}
   ]
   \node[box] (box0) {$S_0$};
   \foreach \i [remember=\i as \lasti (initially 0)] in {1,...,8}
     \draw[-{Latex}] (box\lasti) -- 
              node[above]{$\lambda_\lasti$} ++(1.2,0)   
              node[box, anchor=west] (box\i) {$S_\i$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]